# smooth loop of audio files in android applicatio

Tags: android, loops

I am making android app for musical instrument, where I need smooth looping of the OGG files from RAW folder.. 
Right now it plays well but with small time delay. can someone post a working code for smooth looping of audio files in andriod application.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.  Maybe we can help

Answer (score 0):

read about `MediaPlayer` class and `setLooping(boolean)` method

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html